# fabric.io missing dSYM even after upload

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have the error: "It looks like we are missing dSYMs to process crashes for the versions below." - I have downloaded the dSYMs in the Xcode organiser, found the .xarchive and zipped the corresponding `dSYMs` folder and uploaded with success; but the error does not disappear i.e. does nothing:

How can I symbolicate my crash reports?

[image]

dSYM Folder:
[image]

Comment: are you uploading just the .dSYM zipped up?

Comment: I've tried zipping the whole folder, all the dysms together and just the dsym for the app target

Comment: Thanks @Halpo - try running this command to get the exact dSYM that is missing in a terminal:

mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == <UUID>”

Then, take the .dSYM, zip it up and upload and that should work.

Comment: I used mdfind to get the archive, but which .dSYM file should I zip, there are multiple?

Comment: added a picture of my dSYM folder @MikeBonnell

Comment: Hmm, that should have worked if you uploaded just the xxx.app.dsym, zipped up. Can you send over the zipped dSYM to support(at)fabric(dot)io for me to look into further?

Comment: thanks, I've sent that over @MikeBonnell

Comment: uploaded a new build - exact same problem

Comment: Having the same issue. With all the projects. Did you get this resolved?

Comment: nope, it sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.

Comment: make sure you don't make or use more than 1 build with the same version/build number

Comment: @MikeBonnell this is still happening for me

Comment: @Halpo I'd recommend checking out the improved documentation around this: https://docs.fabric.io/ios/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I just had the same issue and searching for solutions brought me here. Since this is missing an answer and I solved the issue for me, I'll resurrect this question to maybe help others having the same issue in the future.*

Below the part shown in your first screenshot, there should be a list "**REQUIRED  (These are needed before crashes can be processed)**" stating which UUIDs are still missing their dSYM and from which Build they are.
Just download the dSYM of the respective Build(s) like stated in the official [Docs » Crashlytics » All about Missing dSYMs](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#downloading-bitcode-dsyms).
(E.g. log into iTunes, select the respective Build and click on `download dSYM` at the Build Details screen)

The downloaded dSYM(s) can simply be manually uploaded as you already did the other file(s).

Answer (score 1):

I've tried almost all the variants, described here on stack overflow and on Fabric info page, to solve the same issue. But, unfortunately, none of them helped. And I've found a new solution, which I haven't seen here on Stackoverflow and which fitted me.

I've integrated HockeyApp with the project of my app and uploaded the build into HockeyApp (the build is uploaded there with an archive which contains dSYMs). After that the crashes started finally appearing on Crashlytics as symbolicated crashes with details.

Comment: One thing of note: this will also work with Crashlytics Beta.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. The reason was enabled bitcode. So disable it or download dSYMs from iTC and upload them manually. I didn't find bette solutions yet.