# iOS - Crashlytics missing dSYMs to process crashes

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, dsym, google-fabric

I know this is a frequently asked question.

I just spent the entire day looking for answers, without success.

Here are the different posts that helped me, but didn't fix my issue.

**Posts, Documentation, Twitt :**

[Missing dSYM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224306/fabric-io-missing-dsym-even-after-upload), [No matching UUID](https://twittercommunity.com/t/not-matching-uuid-bitcode/61000), [Official Documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#upload-symbols-script) but also [It looks like we are missing dSYMs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906875/could-not-get-crash-report-in-crashlytics-fabric-showing-error-it-looks-li)

**Here is my configuration and what I have tried so far :**

[image]

- I have bitcode enabled (watchOS support)
- I have downloaded dSYM from iTunesConnect -> Without Success
- I searched in the archive from the Organizer (Show Package) -> Without Success
- I have set DWARF with dSYM file in the Build Settings.

I don't have matching UUID, like I read in some posts, it's because Apple compile the App again when you have bitcode enabled.

What should I do now ? We released a new version and now Crashlytics Dashboard is getting messy with all those missing dSYMs, for 2 different versions now.

If someone has additional information that I didn't read or know about, I am open-minded for suggestions.

**NB:** *I have bitcode enabled for my Watch and Watch extension target, and the whole project, but not for my main target nor the widget*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out on this, Todd from Fabric.

We do not currently support WatchOS crashes. We tested heavily when watchOS 2 came out, but unfortunately there were many changes to the APIs in that version. One of the changes heavily restricted our ability to capture information reliably and also get that information out. Since we couldn't do this reliability without using private APIs, we don't have support for it.

Thanks!

Comment: But we have very few users using the Watch. It's impossible that I have 300+ unsymbolicated crashes just from the Watch.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have any dSYMs available in iTC?

Comment: Yes, I have one indeed, when I download it, it doesn't match with the one required by Crashlytics. Even if I upload it, nothing happens. And by the way, I can't have bitcode enable in my App if I don't have all my targets with bitcode enable, so even if I have bitcode for the iWatch, the whole App doesn't bitcode enable.

Comment: Thanks Raphael. Can you run dwarfdump -u path/to/dsym on the dSYM files to find the matching UUID? Also, can you unaccept this answer so I we can work in the comments instead?

Comment: I only have 1 dSYM file in the .zip I downloaded from iTunesConnect. When I ran the dwarfdump on this dSYM file, it matches with my WatchkipAppExtension

Comment: Todd, has this answer changed recently?